# Getting SharedPreference From XML

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I am having problems finding a way to populate a TextView with the value of a SharedPreference using XML.
Is there a way to reference the preference like a string resource.
Something like

TextView android:text="@preference/name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Frank I don't think that will be possible you have to get the get the preference from your xml then set to your  TextView.

```
     SharedPreferences prefs; 


   prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String username = prefs.getString("username", "");

    TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtname.setText(username);
```